# problema con fs.readFileSync(__dir)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, fs

esta es mi primera consulta en el foro!

Estoy siguiendo un curso de node.js y en la carpeta de las rutas, especificamente en el archivo index.js, tengo esto:

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const router = express.Router();

const PATH_ROUTES = __dirname;

const a = fs.readFileSync(PATH_ROUTES);

console.log({a});

module.exports = router;
```

pero me sale este error cuando ejecuto:

```
node:internal/fs/utils:344
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (node:fs:723:3)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:433:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:479:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\usuarios\alumno\Escritorio\Programacion\API REST Node.js Express\routes\index.js:7:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18) {
  errno: -4068,
  syscall: 'read',
  code: 'EISDIR'
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma.

Comment: Quizas esto conteste tu pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959038/npm-stuck-giving-the-same-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que estas usando `fs.readFileSync` para leer un directorio y no un archivo.

Para obtener los archivos del directorio podes usar [`fs.readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirsyncpath-options).

#### Ejemplo:

```
fs.readdirSync(PATH_ROUTES).forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
});
```